# Require module defined in another script

Tags: javascript, requirejs

**Script A**

```
;(function(g){

  define('hotness', [], function() {
    function f() {;
      console.log('gotem');
    }
    return f;
  });

  define('otherModule', [], function() {});


})(this);
```

**Script B**

```
define([
  'ScriptA',
], function() {

  var hotness = require('hotness')
});
```

`Error: Module name "hotness" has not been loaded yet for context: _`

What is the recommended way to require in a definition from ScriptA in ScriptB?

I've also tried:

**Script B Alt**

```
define([
  'require',
  'ScriptA',
  'hotness'
], function(require) {

  var hotness = require('hotness')
});
```

Which gives me

`Error loading resource ... /hotness.js: No such file or directory
Error: Script error for: hotness`

EDIT:

It's important to note that ScriptA stands as is and will not be modified. The question is how can I get at the named module in ScriptA from ScriptB.

EDIT2:

I have no control over the HTML or any other aspect of the page. I must do everything within ScriptB.

EDIT3:

I have an example of something that works but it looks like a horrible antipattern work-around so I didn't even want to mention it:

```
define(['require'], function(require) {
    // why use window? IDK.
    // this is just verbatim what is "working" for someone else
    window.require(['scriptA'], function(sA) {
        //sA never actually used
        window.require([
            'otherModule'
        ], function(oM) {
            var hotness = require('hotness'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`bundles` configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles). Given what you've described works, you should use:

```
bundles: {
    'scriptA': ['hotness', 'otherModule']
}
```

This essentially tells RequireJS "when you want to find `hotness` or `otherModule` then load `scriptA` because they are defined there". I use this every now and then to load modules from bundles that have been generated with `r.js`.

Other than this [Joseph the Dreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33246259/1906307) is correct that you should not in the same module mix the AMD and CommonJS methods of getting dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your ScriptA uses named modules. They must be loaded after RequireJS but prior to any of the dependents. [RequireJS does not recommend named modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) unless you know what you're doing (like load a library like a regular script, and register it as a module at the same time).

> Error: Module name "hotness" has not been loaded yet for context: _

This is a generic RequireJS error, when the module is loaded from the server, but somehow RequireJS can't provide it to the dependent. Usually happens when the module has syntax errors or when there's a circular dependency, among others.

ScriptB also has problems. It's trying to use both [AMD style](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep) (array dependencies) and [CommonJS style](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) (explicit require). Just use one of the two syntaxes. Note that in the CommonJS format, it needs the module to have a first argument named `require` to trigger CommonJS format of writing.

```
define(['hotness'], function(hotness) {
  // use hotness
});

// or

define(function(require){
  var hotness = require('hotness');
  // use hotness
});
```

> Error loading resource ... /hotness.js: No such file or directory

Be sure to set a base url. It can be implicit (based on the [`data-main` location](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main)) or explicit ([using `require.config`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)). Module names are usually paths + filenames relative to the base url.

It is advised that you use one file per module, containing a module definition that has no name (the file name becomes the name of the module) and resides somewhere under the set `baseUrl`.

Comment: ScriptA is not modifiable.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland then make sure it loads after RequireJS but before any of the scripts that require anything inside it.

Comment: base url is set, this is truncated for clarity. location, config, etc are all set... the question is how do I get at the named module in ScriptA from ScriptB

Comment: I have no control over the html either, only over ScriptB. I need to pull in scriptA and refer to its named modules right there.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland Like I said, make sure it loads after RequireJS but before any of the scripts that require anything. How are you loading ScriptB anyways? What creates ScriptA that you can't edit it? Is ScriptA even loaded on the page in one way or another? ScriptA isn't a module file (it has more than one) so it can't load as an AMD module.

Comment: Added an edit to the question to show a way that ScriptA can be loaded via require but it's really ugly so I didn't want to mention it. Script A is not loaded on the page at all otherwise.